# Program that stores colors of the rainbow in array and continually prompts user to enter a value from 7 to -1 to end program

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a university python task, in which I am required to write a program that stores the colors of the rainbow in an array, and then continually prompt the user to enter an integer from 7 to -1 to end the code.

Any help would be much appreciated!

I have been able to creat an array, however I have drawn a blank as to how to create the loop. I current have used an if function to test the output.

```
def r_color(color):
    rainbow = ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Indigo']
    if color == -1:
        print("Invalid Input")
    elif 0 < color <= len(rainbow):
        print(rainbow[color - 1])
    else:
        print("Number not in range")


user_input = int(input("Please select a number to see the color of the rainbow: "))

r_color(user_input)
```

The expected result should be that the program outputs the color and continiously prompts the user to enter an integer from 7 to -1

It currently outputs one value before terminating the program, which is to be expected given I used a if function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while True:` statement and enclose your algorithm. This will make whatever you put inside the while statement repeat for ever. To stop execution, press Ctrl + C. If you want the user to be able to terminate the program, create a Boolean variable and make it the condition of the while loop. Each execution of the while loop should update the Boolean variable value based on user input.

Use the input() function inside the while statement to wait for user input in your algorithm.
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/python/getting-started/input-and-output/tutorial/